# How to interpret "ich dachte, dir ginge das genauso"?

Tags: meaning

> Ich hasse es, wenn ... Und **ich dachte**, dir **ginge** das genauso.

I'm not sure how to interpret the "ich dachte + Konjunktiv" construction:

> 1: I thought you would share my view, but it has ***turned out to be wrong***.
>
> 2:  I hate this, and you would ***surely*** agree with me, right? {***pressuring you to agree***}
>
> 3: In my opinion, you'd agree with me, {but this is nothing more than ***an assumption*** on my part, so it is just ***as likely to be false as it is to be true***.}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ... Und ich dachte, dir ginge das genauso.

could be rephrased to

> ... Und ich dachte, du hättest die gleiche Meinung.

So interpretation 1 is correct.

In this case *»gehen«* has the meaning *»to be in a certain state/condition«* *(sich in einer bestimmten Verfassung, Lage befinden)*.

Note that it's more common to use *»ginge **es**«* instead of *»ginge **das**«*.

Comment: Oh, I see. So I suppose the speaker says this sentence in an accusing or disappointing tone?

Comment: @Alone-zee: Accusation  or disappointment are possible, but also surprise.

Answer (score -1):

Without further context only #3 applies, but already minor additions could shift it to one of the others. E. g. *oder etwa nicht* would shift the meaning towards #2.

To arrive at #1 I would use Plu-perfect *Ich hatte gedacht*, to convey, that I no longer believe it due to new information.